# SQL - Alternatives to a generic datamodel

Tags: sql, database, generics, datamodel

while studying, im struggling to find an answer to this question:

What is a generic datamodel?

Are there any alternatives to a generic datamodel, if so; which one would you recommend?

I've looked everywhere to find a decent answer, but i didn't find it. It might be just a very simple question, i just couldn't find these terms; 'generic datamodel'.

Comment: So who asked you 'what is a generic data model'. Because academic question unfortunately have little bearing on real world problems. This gives us some context for defining this mysterious term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps by generic data model you mean an entity attribute value model: [EAV on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

This data model has one table and three columns. It is usually burnt by fire if ever discovered by someone of a database (vs developer) persuasion.

The thing with a data model is that you are modeling *something*. You are applying your skills to build a database that is optimised to store and retrieve data about something (widgets in a factory, trades on a stock exchange, Facebook posts). A EAV can store all of this stuff but it causes many other problems down the line.

More info here: [EAV](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible its an EAV mode. But that leaves me with the following question: are there any alternatives to this model?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there an alternatives to an EAV model? Yes. Many. Every database that isn't an EAV model is an alternative. But a Facebook post data model does not help you track production of widgets. Can you clarify - is this an academic question?

Answer (score 0):

@ nick, this is the question:

5. Advise in Chapter 5 of the people involved in your case about the application or not of a generic data model
   and optionally other alternatives. Motivate your opinion (10 points).

Comment: So it's an academic question. In this case it does not mean an EAV at all. It means a pre built data model for the business process. i.e. a generic sales business data model will have a sales header table and a sales line item table. A generic online shopping cart will have a certain design. A unique business (i.e. Facebook) won't have a generic data model. I typed "generic sales data model" into google and got this: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/sales_receipts_generic/index.htm